# why gcc is adding .comment and .note.gnu.property section?

Tags: c, gcc, ld

Can anyone explain why gcc is adding the .comment and .note.gnu.property sections in the object code, and how can I tell to gcc not to add them, is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the code you're compiling, which platform you're compiling it for, which version of GCC you're using, and what command you're using to invoke GCC?

Comment: Thank you brother I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why gcc is adding the .comment and .note.gnu.property sections

You can examine the contents of the `.comment` section with e.g. `readelf -x.comment`:

```
echo "int foo() { return 42; }" | gcc -xc - -c -o foo.o
readelf -x.comment foo.o

Hex dump of section '.comment':
  0x00000000 00474343 3a202844 65626961 6e203131 .GCC: (Debian 11
  0x00000010 2e322e30 2d313029 2031312e 322e3000 .2.0-10) 11.2.0.
```

Obviously the "why" is to make it easier to understand what compiler produced the object file.

I don't believe there is a GCC flag to suppress this, but `objcopy --remove-section .comment foo.o bar.o` will get rid of it.

The `.note.gnu.property` can be [removed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52257565/50617) in similar fashion.

Here is a [discussion](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2018-March/121951.html) of what it may contain.

Comment: Ohh thank you very much brother, I have solved my problem with objcopy --remove-section, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

tks makred it, `objcopy -O binary -R .note -R .comment -R .note.gnu.property  foo` , elf format to binary, size from 129M to 4K

Answer (score 1):

Don't remove the `.note.gnu.property`, as it contains data passed to linker, like "stack size," "stack permissions," etc. The binary won't load if `.note.gnu.property` isn't present.